# Waiving library costs if the student has own access

Tags: tuition, digital-libraries

Costs of print and electronic resources including access to journals and books are usually part of tuition fees for PhD and MSc programmes.

Are there universities which waive such costs if the student doesn't need them, e.g., has his/her own or external adequate resources?

Comment: Libraries (usually?) don't pay for access per student, so I'm going to guess this is incredibly unlikely.

Comment: I agree with @MJeffryes - library access and many other things are lumped into 'overhead' - it isn't a long itemized list of support for various university facilities that you can cross this or that off of.

Comment: Also, I don't think universities usually have the infrastructure in place to exclude particular individuals from using library resources. At most institutions, access is available for anyone using the university's IP addresses.

Comment: I'm not sure why you ask this question. I hope you don't intend to choose an institution based on this. Likely there are such places. Likely they are rare. Among other things, such fees provide general support to the library and the containing institution.

Comment: Why would a student have so many subscriptions on their own? Are you enrolled in two different universities?

Comment: Could you specify "external adequate resources"?

Comment: I never use the south walkway behind the dining hall that goes past those statues on the way to the Fine Arts building. I always walk west from the dining hall, into the English building, and take the tunnel to the Fine Arts building. Could I get a tuition discount that prorates out the upkeep costs of that walkway? While we're at it, I never check out "A Tale of Two Cities" from the library because my uncle has a copy, I should get an additional 50 cent discount. Thanks.

Comment: @Robert. Irrelevant comment. I didn't call for tuition fees waiving. I asked whether there are universities which allow that. Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 5):

I have never heard of such a thing.  Such access is always made available to all students, and any associated fees would be mandatory.  They might be waived on the basis of financial need, but not on an "opt out" basis.

With a policy like you suggest, I'd be worried about students opting out to save a little money, and then discovering they needed access more than they thought, with an adverse impact on their studies.

Also, on a practical level, these systems are usually not designed to be able to grant or deny access to individual students, so they couldn't easily restrict access to those who had paid.  Often access is on the basis of IP address range, so that all you need is to sit down at any computer on the campus network, without any further authentication.